Error al interactuar con MYSQl utilizando mysql2/promise async/await en node.js
El siguiente código de la versión (1) funciona perfectamente y también en la versión (3).
Sin embargo al tratar de exportar desde un archivo externo consumiendo mysql2/promise me dice que
Callback function is not available with promise clients.

¿Por qué?
No encuentro diferencia entre exportar desde database.js o usarla directamente en querys.js
//En la raiz app,js solo codigo de esta consulta 

const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const  actorsRouter = require ('./routes/actors')
const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extend//

// dentro carpeta route archivo actors.js 

const {Router} =require ('express');
const db = require ('../querys');
const router =Router();

router.get('/',async (req,res) => {
    const query =await db.executeQuery();
    return res.status (201).json(query)
})
module.exports = router;

// en raiz archivo querys.js 
//(1)!!!!!

const mysql=require('mysql2/promise');
const pool = mysql.createPool({
  host                  : 'localhost',
  user                  : 'root',
  password              : 'TU PASS',
  database              : 'sakila',
  waitForConnections    : true,
  connectionLimit       : 3,
  maxIdle               : 3, // max idle connections, the default value is the same as `connectionLimit`
  idleTimeout           : 60000, // idle connections timeout, in milliseconds, the default value 60000
  queueLimit            : 0,
  enableKeepAlive       : true,
  keepAliveInitialDelay : 0,
  port: "3307",
});


async function executeQuery() {

  const connection = await pool.getConnection();
  console.log('connection :',connection)
  console.log('Connected to the MySQL server.');
  const [rows,fields] = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM sakila.actor');
  return rows;
}

exports.executeQuery = executeQuery;
// responde adecuadamente a GET http://localhost:3000/actors/

/*Codigo anterior funciona sin problemas pero si trato de usar la promesa pool  
desde un archivo database.js  
externo 

*/
// database.js
// (2) !!!!!!

const pool = mysql.createPool({
    host : 'localhost',
    user : 'root',
    password : 'tu pass',
    database :'sakila',
    port: '3307',
    connectionLimit : 15
});
exports,pool = pool;

//luego al tratar de usar a pool desde querys,js con el siguiente codigo

const pool = require('./database').pool;

async function executeQuery() {

  const connection = await pool.getConnection();
  console.log('connection :',connection)
  console.log('Connected to the MySQL server.');
  const [rows,fields] = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM sakila.actor');
  return rows;
}

exports.executeQuery = executeQuery;

Callback function is not available with promise clients.
Error: Callback function is not available with promise clients.
    at PromisePool.query (C:\Personal\CreateConnection\node_modules\mysql2\promise.js:358:13)
    at C:\Personal\CreateConnection\routes\actors.js:9:10
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Personal\CreateConnection\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Personal\CreateConnection\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:149:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Personal\CreateConnection\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:119:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Personal\CreateConnection\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Personal\CreateConnection\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:15
    at Function.process_params (C:\Personal\CreateConnection\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:346:12)
    at next (C:\Personal\CreateConnection\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:10)
    at Function.handle (C:\Personal\CreateConnection\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:175:3)

//  si en lugar de consumir  mysql2/promise desde   querys.js requiero solo mysql2

// Tambien como en (1) !!!! funciona sin errores
// vecion (3) !!!
//solo requiereo mysql2
const mysql = require('mysql2');
var pool= mysql.createPool({
    host : 'localhost',
    user : 'root',
    password : 'tu pass',
    database :'sakila',
    port: '3307',
    connectionLimit : 15
});
 
exports.pool = pool;


Hay un monton de codigo y es confuso.. podrias formatear el codigo como corresponde y explicar bien donde esta cada cosa y que causa el error?

El problema principal es que en la versión que falla, estás tratando de usar el método query con el objeto pool directamente, el cual no está configurado para soportar el uso de callbacks con clientes de promesas.
En la versión fallida, debes obtener una conexión del pool y luego usar esa conexión para ejecutar la consulta. Aquí tienes una corrección para database.js y querys.js:


#database.js

const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');
const pool = mysql.createPool({
    host : 'localhost',
    user : 'root',
    password : 'tu pass',
    database :'sakila',
    port: '3307',
    connectionLimit : 15
});
module.exports = pool;

#querys.js
const pool = require('./database').pool;

async function executeQuery() {
    const connection = await pool.getConnection();
    try {
        console.log('Connected to the MySQL server.');
        const [rows, fields] = await connection.query('SELECT * FROM sakila.actor');
        return rows;
    } finally {
        connection.release();
    }
}

module.exports = { executeQuery };



Aquí, database.js exporta el pool correctamente utilizando module.exports. En querys.js, obtienes una conexión del pool y luego realizas la consulta usando esa conexión, asegurándote de liberar la conexión después de usarla.

no soluciona el problema responde TypeError: pool.getConnection is not a function
at Object.executeQuery (C:\Personal\Libreria\express-locallibrary-tutorial\querys.js:3:33)

si en tu codigo modificas ------> module.exports={pool];   por module.exports=pool; si entonces  funciona por favor edita tu respuesta de esa forma asi es valida y la puedo reconocer como tal gracias

modifica a module.exports=pool asi funciona y puedo dar como valida la respuesta
